# Create new External Storage for Nextcloud

Tags: php, symfony, add-on, symfony-3.4, nextcloud

I want to create a new external storage for Nextcloud like amazonS3, FTP, OwnCloud, etc. But with my own storage API, however there is no documentation on Nextcloud to do that. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All existing external storage connectors are found in the git repository [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/tree/master/apps/files_external/lib/Lib/Backend).

Authentication methods are [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/tree/master/apps/files_external/lib/Lib/Auth).

There are plenty of examples there for you to review.